# Global variables in driver affecting one another

Tags: c, variables, driver, global

I am experiencing a weird problem regarding global variables in a WFP driver I'm writing. After writing a piece of code I started to get 0x18 bugchecks in the entirely different part of my code, not related to the written one - moreover it occured even before the new piece of code got to be executed. After a short analysis I noticed that it was caused by declaration of a global variable, which with new piece commented out was ommited by the compiler. As soon as the variable was used, it got placed in the memory and bugchecks started to occur. My first thought was, that maybe I should try changing the order of how the variables are declared, and thus, how there are placed in the memory (I think). As it turned out, after a couple of tries I was able to run the code correctly. An example of a code, that is NOT working:

```
PKEVENT gPacketEvent;

HANDLE gFilteringEngineHandle;
HANDLE gInjectionEngineHandle;
PVOID gUASharedMem;
PVOID gSharedMem;

UINT64 gActiveFilter;
UINT32 gCalloutID;

PMDL gMdl;
```

I am guessing that one or more of the types (I guess PMDL and PKEVENT?) I used above can cause such problems, but unfortunately I have never seen such a behaviour, and I haven't been able to find anything useful on google. I was able to develop this code for a while, changing the order back and forth to find a working one, but it would be great to get to the bottom of this... Any ideas, why does this happen?

Comment: It is common for programmers to write outside the limits of a variable; which is the most common cause of what you describe. Perhaps there is an array that is written one element beyond its dimension, etc.  However, the question does not supply enough information to diagnose.  If there is a specific variable that is changing its value unexpectedly, I would put a 'breakpoint' on that memory (in a debugger) and find out what is changing it.  Can't really go much further unless more of the surrounding code is supplied.

Comment: Compile your code at warning level `/W4` and also do a build with `prefast`. You might be doing something obvious that static analysis can identify. Also, using Driver Verifier on your driver can help identify bugs when the problem code executes (vs. when you see a distant side-effect).

Comment: Both of your suggestions were helpful. As it turned out I passed a handle to one of the functions instead of a simple structure. What's weird, is that code used to work at most of the times, just taking in garbage from unallocated memory as data... Thank you very much!